# Specifying Maven's local repository location as a CLI parameter

Tags: maven

Is it possible to set the location of the local Maven repository as argument on the Maven command line?

The thing is that I don't use the default one in `~/.m2/repository`. However I checked out some project that is being built with its own settings with `-s settings.xml`. That settings.xml doesn't specify my local repository, so Maven uses uses `~/.m2/repository` again... I would like to use a non-default local repository location without having to add a `<localRepository>` element in the project's settings.xml

I've tried

- `-DlocalRepository="..."`
- `$mvn invoker:run -s settings.xml clean install -DskipTests -DlocalRepositoryPath=`
- `-Dsettings.localRepository`

but none of these options works.

So I think I have to decide whether I will be modifying a third party settings.xml or move my local repo to `~`

Comment: Obviously this is not your fault, but Maven projects shouldn't be providing a `settings.xml`. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html

Answer (score 340, accepted):

use maven property `maven.repo.local`:

`mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=$HOME/.my/other/repository clean install`

No modifications to `settings.xml` are necessary.

Comment: The local repository must be an absolute path, https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html.

Comment: On Windows use
`
mvn -D"maven.repo.local"=%USER_HOME%/.my/other/repository clean install
`

Comment: Using maven-3.6.3 the local repository dir works as a relative path (on MacOS at least)

Comment: Here is the official docs that mention this: https://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-model-builder/index.html

Comment: @powder366 Environment variable? `MAVEN_OPTS=-D"maven.repo.local"=%USER_HOME%/.my/other/repository` might work. Or `~/.mavenrc`?

Answer (score 14):

For git:

```
alias mvn='mvn "-Dmaven.repo.local=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/.m2/repository"'
```

This uses a separate maven repository in each git repository

Answer (score 2):

One kind of hacky way that would work is:

1. Add `<localRepository>${m2.localRepository}</localRepository>` to your settings.xml
2. In your mvn.sh or mvn.bat, add `-Dm2.localRepository=<full path to home dir>/.m2/repository` *before* the "$@" in the command that gets executed. This will make your default local repo stay where it should be.
3. Now you can use `mvn -Dm2.localRepository=... <phases/goals>`. Because your command line system property gets added to the command line after the one in the mvn script, it will take precedence. (At least I'm pretty sure it works that way on both windows and linux, but testing will tell.)

Comment: That doesn't help, I added -Dm2.localRepository="custom" before "$@" into mvn script, still uses ~/.m2/repository ... then I also included -Dm2.localRepository="custom" when running $mvn,  still uses ~/.m2/repository ...simply without localRepository element in the settings.xml, there is no way of changing it

Comment: @lisak: Did you do step 1 of adding the localRepository element to the settings.xml? I tested this, and it works, except that you can't actually use the '~' alias in the mvn script. You have to put an absolute path in, though you could probably do some other shell/batch script trickery to get around that.

Comment: It works, but I really don't have explanation... If I declare localRepository in $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml without step 2, it is overriden by -s settings.xml and doesn't work, though with step 2 it works ... but only step 2 without localRepository in $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml doesn't work ... both steps 1,2 must be applied for it to work and I can even change the location then via $mvn -Dm2.localRepository=..   thanks Ryan