# Force re-download of release dependency using Maven

Tags: maven-2, maven, dependency-management, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm working on a project with dependency X. X, in turn, depends on Y.

I used to explicitly include Y in my project's pom. However, it was not used and to make things cleaner, I instead added it to X's pom as a dependency. X is marked as a release dependency.

The problem is that after removing Y from my project's pom and adding it to X's pom, my project isn't picking it up on `mvn -U clean package`. I know -U update snapshots but not releases.

So, *without deleting the ~/.m2/repository directory* how can I force a re-download of X's pom? Also, I tried running `dependency:purge-local-repository` and it didn't work either.

Comment: You've tagged the questions as "maven-2". The -U option was added in Maven 3 to solve this problem. I'd suggest upgrading.

Comment: Just from a methodology perspective, if you change `X`'s pom, then it should constitute a new release, even if it's only a patch number change: `1.3` -> `1.3.1`. So, that would eliminate this problem from the get-go.

Comment: However, it's still possible to have similar issues with snapshots as well, so it's good to have some answers.

Comment: As a point of reference -U does "affect" released versions, but only by downloading them if they have never been successfully downloaded before. Weird mix. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29020716/maven-what-does-u-update-snapshots-really-do/29020990#29020990

Comment: `dependency:purge-local-repository` should work, does it not delete it?

Comment: To make question clearer there should be explicit indication that there are 3 projects involved, not 2: "I'm working on a project Z with dependency on X" and "I moved dependency on Y from Z to X project".

Answer (score 240, accepted):

You cannot make Maven re-download dependencies, but what you can do instead is to purge dependencies that were incorrectly downloaded using `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository`

See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/purge-local-repository-mojo.html

This looks up the list of all transitive dependencies of the current project, deletes them, then redownloads them.  You can even add it as a plugin into your pom if you want to run it with every build.

Comment: Isn't that kind of the same thing?

Comment: It doesn't require access to the file system which might be an issue if you're only configuring build jobs (for a CI system for example).

Comment: If multiple project run `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository clean package`, may be one project delete the same dependency in local repository while another project is running compile. How to avoid?

Comment: @vikyd, not sure if this is the best way, but you could use the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable to force maven to download/use dependencies from a different folder from the standard `.m2/respository` location, like so:  

`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Dmaven.repo.local=${PROJECT_DIR}/maven.repository`  


This will prevent maven from using any dependencies in the normal folder and use the one specified by `Dmaven.repo.local=` instead.

Answer (score 76):

Based on Ali Tokmen answer. I managed to force delete a single specific local dependency with the following command:

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude=com.skyfish:utils
```

With this, it removes `utils` from my .m2/repository and it always re-download the `utils` JAR dependency when I proceed to run `mvn clean install`.  If you want something more programmatic possibly also see the `-Dinclude=...` option.

Comment: I simply needed a way to force maven to re-download a dependency. This is the only answer that actually does that, whereas other answers suggest removing everything. Thank you

Comment: On Windows you should add quotes around the package. So, for example: `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository -DmanualInclude="jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api"`

Answer (score 70):

I just deleted my ~/.m2/repository and that forced a re-download ;)

Comment: It helps as a last resort, I had a project where eclipse and maven were a bit "confused". Simply deleting the .m2 folder made the project compile and run correctly.

Comment: It's also possible to selectively delete the dependencies that you know need to be refreshed from inside the repository. A manual purge, if you will.

Answer (score 62):

I think following command may help you!

---

```
mvn -U clean install
```

Comment: **release dependency using Maven** in the question. No, this might have been better a comment.

Answer (score 22):

```
mvn clean install -U
```

-U means force update of dependencies.

If you want to update a single dependency without clean or -U you could just remove it from your local repo and then build.

Comment: Again, this only re-downloads SNAPSHOT dependencies.

Answer (score 16):

Project right click-> Maven -> Update Project
and check the checkboxes as in the screen shot. It will update releases as well :)

[image]

Comment: It would be nice to know how they implemented that "/Releases" part.

Comment: Thanks for this just what I needed.

Comment: Is this Netbeans?  Regardless, I'm guessing that checkbox means to supply the `-U` command to maven, which "kind of" updates releases https://stackoverflow.com/a/29020990/32453 but not the way the OP was looking for :)

Answer (score 9):

If you know the group id of `X`, you can use this command to redownload all of `X` and it's dependencies

```
mvn clean dependency:purge-local-repository -DresolutionFuzziness=org.id.of.x
```

It does the same thing as the other answers that propose using `dependency:purge-local-repository`, but it only deletes and redownloads everything related to `X`.

Answer (score 8):

When you added it to X, you should have incremented X's version number i.e X-1.2
Then X-1.2 should have been installed/deployed and you should have changed your projects dependency on X to be dependent on the new version X-1.2

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to force-download all dependencies, you can try to re-initialise the entire maven repository. Like in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823462/specifying-mavens-local-repository-location-as-a-cli-parameter) already described, you could use:

```
mvn -Dmaven.repo.local=$HOME/.my/other/repository clean install
```

Answer (score 3):

Just delete ~/.m2/repository...../actual_path where the invalid LOC is coming as it forces to re-download the deleted jar files. **Dont delete the whole repository folder** instead delete the specific folder from where the error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the `~/.m2/repository` will solve your problem. But, if you still need to **keep** the old `~/.m2/repository` you can just change the maven local path temporarily.

If you are working on IntelliJ just go to Maven Settings and change the Local Repository path to somewhere else. You may need to tick the override checkbox near there.

[image]

Comment: Please read the question: "So, without deleting the ~/.m2/repository directory ....."

Answer (score -3):

Go to build path... delete existing maven library u added... click add library ... click maven managed dependencies... then click maven project settings... check resolve maven dependencies check box..it'll download all maven dependencies

Comment: This assumes use of some IDE, an assumption not supported by the question, and you didn't even specify what IDE!

Answer (score -4):

Most answers provided above would solve the problem.

But if you use IntelliJ and want it to just fix it for you automatically, go to Maven Settings.

Build,Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven

[image]

Disable Work Offline

Enable Always update snapshots (Switch when required)

Comment: I would appreciate if you can also share the reason of downvote while you are at it. Thank you.

Comment: Presumably, because snapshots are not releases, so this does not solve the problem.