# Unable to package my Spring boot application as a runnable fat Jar

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I am a bit new to Spring boot and below is my application's POM/Java file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.aj.stuff.install</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyProject</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>Some-Name</name>
    <description>Some Stuff</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>MyProject</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

The main java application code snippet is as below -

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
...
```

Now when i try to run the command mvn package i get below error -

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ MY-Bootstrap ---
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-loader-tools:jar:1.4.1.RELEASE is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available,
able debug logging for more details
[WARNING] Error injecting: org.springframework.boot.maven.RepackageMojo
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/LaunchScript
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2671)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2020)
        at com.google.inject.spi.InjectionPoint.forConstructorOf(InjectionPoint.java:245)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl.create(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:99)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createUninitializedBinding(InjectorImpl.java:658)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:882)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.createJustInTimeBindingRecursive(InjectorImpl.java:805)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getJustInTimeBinding(InjectorImpl.java:282)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getBindingOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:214)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProviderOrThrow(InjectorImpl.java:1006)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1038)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getProvider(InjectorImpl.java:1001)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.space.AbstractDeferredClass.get(AbstractDeferredClass.java:48)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.provision(ProviderInternalFactory.java:81)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.provision(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:53)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory$1.call(ProviderInternalFactory.java:65)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:115)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.bean.BeanScheduler$Activator.onProvision(BeanScheduler.java:176)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback$Provision.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:126)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProvisionListenerStackCallback.provision(ProvisionListenerStackCallback.java:68)
        at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderInternalFactory.circularGet(ProviderInternalFactory.java:63)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToInitializableAdapter.java:45)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:1016)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
        at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1012)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.Guice4$1.get(Guice4.java:162)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
        at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:263)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:255)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getConfiguredMojo(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:517)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:121)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.loader.tools.LaunchScript
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy.loadClass(SelfFirstStrategy.java:50)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.unsynchronizedLoadClass(ClassRealm.java:271)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:247)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.realm.ClassRealm.loadClass(ClassRealm.java:239)
        ... 55 more
```

I have tried excluding repackage as mentioned in many other posts, but no good.
Any suggestions?

OS - Win 7 64 Bit

Maven - Apache Maven 3.3.9 (bb52d8502b132ec0a5a3f4c09453c07478323dc5; 2015-11-10T22:11:47+05:30)

Also I picked a bare bone project from the spring intializr and tried `mvn package` and same error. Any issues related to my machine, maven or anything else?

Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `spring-loader` directory from the `.m2` directory in your home directory. Looks like it it broken/corrupted from an earlier download. You could also remove the whole `.m2` directory but that would force to download everything you ever downloaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the exception you got, the download for the `spring-loaded` dependency got corrupted.

Find the directory in which maven downloads the dependencies (by default the `.m2` directory in your user dir). Find the `spring-loaded` directory and remove it. This will force maven to download the dependency again.

Instead of manually removing the dependencies you could also use the Maven dependency plugin to purge entires.

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

This should remove the dependencies from the `.m2` directory and force a re-download on the next `mvn package`. (See [Force re-download of release dependency using Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959499/force-re-download-of-release-dependency-using-maven))

Answer (score 0):

Looks like wrong version of spring-boot-loader-tools.jar is loaded. This [link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/5560) might help you to fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

the spring boo loader tools jar file is corrupted

remove this folder from your local repository and run maven install to download the jar file again

> \.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-loader-tools