# Unable to instantiate FirefoxDriver class in selenium even though class is present inside JAR

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have downloaded all the necessary jar files from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/)

I am unable to import and start a new instance of Firefox driver even though I am able too see that the jar(`client-combined-3.4.0-nodeps.jar`) have FirefoxDriver class as well.

Line `import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver` is giving compilation error. Unable to resolve error.

Complete code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;//Error

public class FirstTestCase {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\\\ToolsQA\\trunk\\Library\\drivers\\geckodriver.exe");


        //This line is giving the error. I can see FirfoxDriver class inside Jar.

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        //Launch the Online Store Website
        driver.get("http://www.store.demoqa.com");

        // Print a Log In message to the screen
        System.out.println("Successfully opened the website www.Store.Demoqa.com");

        //Wait for 5 Sec
        Thread.sleep(5);

        // Close the driver
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

wondering why this error is coming

Comment: Post the full error so that others can help

Comment: @Peter editing now. It is compilation error

Comment: the error that am getting is `firefox driver can not be resolved to a type`

Comment: Try capitalizing the "d": `FirefoxDriver`

Comment: Already did. Update the question as well

Answer (score 0):

What IDE do you use?

I tried with Eclipse by manually importing the jar (Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add External JARS...) or through a Maven dependency. Both worked.

Seems that your project is corrupted. Try cleaning/refreshing it.

If using Maven, sometimes, when downloading dependencies, they are stored corrupted. Try erasing the directory `org.seleniumhq` into your local Maven repository to force Maven to download it again. Please, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959499/force-re-download-of-release-dependency-using-maven) about details.

And finally, try to download the ZIP again and re-importing it again.

Comment: I am doing it Manually in Eclipse on Windows 10. Going to try using Maven as well.

Comment: @BobRivers doesn't `mvn clean` flushes out all the previous dependencies clean?

Comment: @Dev No. It will clean the generated files inside targer directory. Dependencies are managed by 'install' goal. This post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959499/force-re-download-of-release-dependency-using-maven) has great tips about how troubleshoot it.

Answer (score 0):

It was problem with eclipse Version. I was using eclipse helios. I replaced it with Neon and it started working fine.

Comment: As explained earlier, it was a compilation error. I am still able to reproduce with Eclipse helios.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the same issue on neon.

Comment: delete your maven repository . That should solve your problem.

Comment: well it actually solves the issue when you delete eclipse repo too from mvn repo.