# Error when I downgrade primefaces dependency version from 6.0 to 5.3

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jsf, javabeans

I was using primefaces version 5.3 and it was working fine but I had to upgrade it to version 6.0 to use some  more components.

Many errors started to happen and I went back to 5.3 but even more errors started to happen. I though it was some errors in my application since I did some changes in the mean time but then I trie to upgrade primefaces dependency to last version 6.2, many errors stoped to happen and I went back to version 6.0 and more errors happened, more errors than the first time I changed from 5.3 to 6.0.

I believe primefaces changed something more in my code and than it's version.

this is the errors that occur while i'm at version 5.3 after all this mess:

```
25-Nov-2018 19:37:11.370 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 19:37:11.370 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 19:39:16.381 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 19:39:16.381 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 19:41:34.435 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 19:41:34.435 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 20:20:31.556 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 20:20:31.556 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 20:20:31.572 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.context.ApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance()Lorg/primefaces/context/ApplicationContext;
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.java:30)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1435)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

25-Nov-2018 20:20:47.479 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 20:20:47.479 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 20:22:24.606 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 20:22:24.610 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 20:22:24.615 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.context.ApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance()Lorg/primefaces/context/ApplicationContext;
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.java:30)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1435)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

25-Nov-2018 20:23:36.603 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 20:23:36.603 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 20:23:37.561 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.context.ApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance()Lorg/primefaces/context/ApplicationContext;
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.java:30)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.undeploy(ManagerServlet.java:1416)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:621)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

25-Nov-2018 20:30:34.081 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 20:30:34.081 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 20:30:34.097 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.context.ApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance()Lorg/primefaces/context/ApplicationContext;
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.java:30)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1435)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

25-Nov-2018 20:31:41.363 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 20:31:41.363 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 20:31:41.779 GRAVE [http-nio-8080-exec-8] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.context.ApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance()Lorg/primefaces/context/ApplicationContext;
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.java:30)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.undeploy(ManagerServlet.java:1416)
    at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.doGet(ManagerServlet.java:364)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:621)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestFilterValve.process(RequestFilterValve.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve.invoke(RemoteAddrValve.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:790)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

25-Nov-2018 20:34:01.763 GRAVE [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.context.ApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance()Lorg/primefaces/context/ApplicationContext;
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.java:30)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.reload(StandardContext.java:3793)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.reload(HostConfig.java:1411)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.checkResources(HostConfig.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1620)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:314)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1388)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1392)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1360)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

25-Nov-2018 20:34:15.605 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 20:34:15.605 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 20:34:15.621 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class [com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener]
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.primefaces.context.ApplicationContext.getCurrentInstance()Lorg/primefaces/context/ApplicationContext;
    at org.primefaces.webapp.PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.processEvent(PreDestroyApplicationEventListener.java:30)
    at javax.faces.event.SystemEvent.processListener(SystemEvent.java:108)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.processListeners(ApplicationImpl.java:2169)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.invokeListenersFor(ApplicationImpl.java:2142)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.publishEvent(ApplicationImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:352)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5429)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1435)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StopChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1424)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

25-Nov-2018 20:36:12.923 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 20:36:12.923 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 21:07:16.650 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 21:07:16.650 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 21:07:32.253 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 21:07:32.253 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 21:08:05.328 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 21:08:05.328 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
25-Nov-2018 21:09:30.372 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log ContextListener: contextInitialized()
25-Nov-2018 21:09:30.372 INFORMAÇÕES [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log SessionListener: contextInitialized()
```

Comment: You might want to try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29630060/6660678) and/or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18219588/6660678) to see if they help.  Sometimes Maven gets stuck (Maven Update Project, Force Update of Snapshot Releases) or corrupted (delete repository) and it needs help to resolve the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow I fixed the error, I don't exactly know how but I did. I simple removed (saved a copy first) the .m2 directory and let netbeans create it again.

Unfortunately it wasn't working very well, then I removed this new .m2 directory and went back to the copy I had saved.

And it started to work.

Like I said, I have no ideia why this happened.