# How to ask intelliJ to force download maven dependencies during build?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I did not find any options. It reads existing dependency from my `.m2` directory and unless I manually delete that directory, IntelliJ does not downloads it. Or I think its job of maven!!

So, how can I give this information to IntelliJ for

1. individual dependencies as well as
2. read and update any updated dependency from remote?

Comment: IDE will download the dependency only if it has changed. Otherwise it uses the dependency from the local repository. Also to force update snapshot dependencies from remote, enable Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | **Always update snapshots**. Check also https://stackoverflow.com/a/8624906/2000323

Answer (score 1):

If you run Maven with the option `-U` it redownloads the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

just edit Pom.xml eg:type a space ，idea will pop up you should reimport maven。