# How can i force update of maven dependencies sources?

Tags: maven, dependency-injection, dependencies

I know that i can get maven source dependencies using

```
mvn dependency:sources
```

But i get a lot of corrupted source code jars and i want to redownload them ?

how can i do that ?

Regards

Comment: Build your project with `-U` flag.

Comment: `-U`is for updating snapshot versions. Check these [`answers`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959499/force-re-download-of-release-dependency-using-maven) for how to deal with released versions as well.

Comment: @second All right, you need to purge first. Sorry, I forgot.