# How to specify an alternate location for the .m2 folder or settings.xml permanently?

Tags: maven

I am using Maven 3.0, and my `.m2` folder location is `C:\Users\me\.m2`.

However, I do not have write access to that folder, but I want to change the repository location from the one defined in the `settings.xml`.

Due to restricted access, **I am not able to edit the `settings.xml`** to change the repository location.

How can I override the values of my `settings.xml` -or change the default location of the `.m2` folder- without editing my `C:\Users\me\.m2\conf\settings.xml` file?

Comment: You can use -gs option in command line to set settings.xml path (http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/running-sect-options.html)

Comment: @yodamad. Thank you for the reply. I am getting error as "No goals have been specified". My objective is to make sure that for every build, it should take custom setings.xml, not for a particular build. Can you tell me how to achieve that.

Comment: I am running the script files, hence I want to make it common for all.

Comment: It's also possible from the command line, ex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823462/specifying-mavens-local-repository-location-as-a-cli-parameter

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You need to add this line into your `settings.xml` (or uncomment if it's already there).

```
<localRepository>C:\Users\me\.m2\repo</localRepository>
```

Also it's possible to run your commands with `mvn clean install -gs C:\Users\me\.m2\settings.xml` - this parameter will force maven to use different `settings.xml` then the default one (which is in `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am getting error as "No goals have been specified". My intention is to make sure that for every build, it should take custom setings.xml, not for a particular build. Can you tell me how to achieve that.

Comment: And I have already mentioned that I do not have write access to default .m2 repository.

Comment: If you want to set different `.m2` location globally, then you need to modify `$HOME/.m2/settings.xml`, I am not aware of any other way how to achieve this.

Comment: And for the first question, what is your command?Try the one in my asnwer, I have edited it.

Comment: For me this alone didnt work. I had to copy the settings.xml aswell into the default directory to get it working (C:\Users\MYNAME\.m2)

Comment: 2023 still works :D

Answer (score 69):

*It's funny how other answers ignore the fact that you can't write to that file...*

There are a few workarounds that come to my mind which could help use an arbitrary `C:\redirected\settings.xml` and **use the `mvn` command as usual** happily ever after.

#### `mvn` alias

In a Unix shell (or on Cygwin) you can create

```
alias mvn='mvn --global-settings "C:\redirected\settings.xml"'
```

so when you're calling `mvn blah blah` from anywhere the config is "automatically" picked up.
See [How to create alias in `cmd`?](https://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp) if you want this, but don't have a Unix shell.

#### `mvn` wrapper

Configure your environment so that `mvn` is resolved to a wrapper script when typed in the command line:

- Remove your `MVN_HOME/bin` or `M2_HOME/bin` from your `PATH` so `mvn` is not resolved any more.
- Add a folder to `PATH` (or use an existing one)
- In that folder create an `mvn.bat` file with contents:

  ```
  call C:\your\path\to\maven\bin\mvn.bat --global-settings "C:\redirected\settings.xml" %*
  ```

Note: if you want some projects to behave differently you can just create `mvn.bat` in the same folder as `pom.xml` so when you run plain `mvn` it resolves to the local one.

*Use `where mvn` at any time to check how it is resolved, the first one will be run when you type `mvn`.*

#### `mvn.bat` hack

If you have write access to `C:\your\path\to\maven\bin\mvn.bat`, edit the file and add `set MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARG` to the `:runm2` part:

```
@REM Start MAVEN2
:runm2
set MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS=--global-settings "C:\redirected\settings.xml" %MAVEN_CMD_LINE_ARGS%
set CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER=...
```

#### `mvn.sh` hack

For completeness, you can change the `C:\your\path\to\maven\bin\mvn` shell script too by changing the `exec "$JAVACMD"` command's

```
${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@"
```

part to

```
${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} --global-settings "C:\redirected\settings.xml" "$@"
```

#### Suggestion/Rant

As a person in IT it's funny that you don't have access to your own home folder, for me this constitutes as incompetence from the company you're working for: this is equivalent of hiring someone to do software development, but not providing even the possibility to use anything other than notepad.exe or Microsoft Word to edit the source files. I'd suggest to contact your help desk or administrator and request write access at least to that particular file so that you can change the path of the local repository.

***Disclaimer***: None of these are tested for this particular use case, but I successfully used all of them previously for various other software.

Comment: Well, personally, I am here looking for ways to unobtrusively hijack installs for dynamically checked out projects, and I don't _want_ to edit the settings.xml.  Additionally, if an organization allows users to bring their own device, or hires contractors, it may be better to force the use of a different settings.xml automatically, rather than relying on users to set it up correctly (and, for example, avoid accidental deployment of closed source jars to open source repositories).

Answer (score 63):

Nobody suggested this, but you can use `-Dmaven.repo.local` command line argument to change where the repository is at. In addition, according to `settings.xml` documentation, you can set `-Dmaven.home` where it looks for the `settings.xml` file.

See: [Settings.xml documentation](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Comment: [docs](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.8.2/maven-model-builder/index.html) where `maven.repo.local` is mentioned.

Comment: This is ideal for some CI/CD setups where you need to dynamically inject it.

Answer (score 25):

Below is the configuration in Maven software by default in **MAVEN_HOME\conf\settings.xml**.

```
<settings>
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ~/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->
```

Add the below line under this configuration, will fulfill the requirement.

```
<localRepository>custom_path</localRepository>
```

Ex: `<localRepository>D:/MYNAME/settings/.m2/repository</localRepository>`

Answer (score 10):

You can change the default location of .m2 directory in **m2.conf** file. It resides in your maven installation directory.

add modify this line in

**`m2.conf`**

`set maven.home C:\Users\me\.m2`

Answer (score -1):

You can point to a `different-settings.xml` when you deploy your project. When deployed *from the project folder* you can have a relative path to *get back to your home folder*:

```
mvn clean deploy -s ../../.m2/different-settings.xml
```

Comment: Pnly works if you type it correctly every time on the cli,  one typo any it downloads the internet.  Ops say "permanently"