# Maven specify settings file location via MAVEN_OPTS

Tags: java, maven

I need to use maven with a settings file in a specific location, normally you can give `MAVEN_OPTS` env variable but they are passed to JVM so the following will yield:

```
$ MAVEN_OPTS="-s /settings.xml"
$ mvn clean
Unrecognized option: -s
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I searched a lot but found two keys, `org.apache.maven.user-settings` and `org.apache.maven.global-settings` which is explained [here](https://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/alfresco-sdk-install-maven-opts.html) but it seemed it was working with Maven 2 only. Aliasing `mvn` to `mvn -s /settings.xml` would probably work but I do not like it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27503199/2970947

Comment: Can you provide details on why you need to use a separate settings.xml?

Comment: First it would be useful to know why you need a separate settings.xml as already @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen asked. Furthermore you might can use  `.mvn/maven.config`? See release notes https://maven.apache.org/docs/3.3.1/release-notes.html

Comment: @khmarbaise I have used Maven for very long and I have missed the announcement of this functionality (which is a major step forward - I hail the new architects).   Is it well described in the official documentation too?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Can you explain what you define as the official documentation? Do you have an expectation where it should be documented apart from that release notes?

Comment: @khmarbaise I had a closer look.  My intuitive expectation would be that the page that explains the command line flags thoroughly had a section of how to do this.  Apparently such a page is not online.  The closest is https://maven.apache.org/configure.html which has a single line explaining the exisiance of .mvn and two XML-files but without any further links.  Also https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html has a section on optional configuration which only mentions settings.xml.   Have I overlooked anything?

Comment: @khmarbaise I too have used maven for a long time and wanted the .mvn/maven.config functionality and I was not aware. If you have any influence in the maven doc I would suggest making this more obvious.  I would also suggest that a ~/.mvn (%USERPROFILE%\.mvn for windows) would also be extremely useful.

Answer (score 7):

From the `mvn` shell script:

```
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Apache Maven Startup Script
#
# Environment Variable Prerequisites
#
#   JAVA_HOME       Must point at your Java Development Kit installation.
#   MAVEN_OPTS      (Optional) Java runtime options used when Maven is executed.
#   MAVEN_SKIP_RC   (Optional) Flag to disable loading of mavenrc files.
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

so MAVEN_OPTS contains JVM arguments, not Maven arguments (which is consistent with the error message indicating the JVM doesn't like your arguments).

The actual invocation is

```
exec "$JAVACMD" \
  $MAVEN_OPTS \
  $MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS \
  -classpath "${CLASSWORLDS_JAR}" \
  "-Dclassworlds.conf=${MAVEN_HOME}/bin/m2.conf" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${MAVEN_HOME}" \
  "-Dlibrary.jansi.path=${MAVEN_HOME}/lib/jansi-native" \
  "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=${MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR}" \
  ${CLASSWORLDS_LAUNCHER} "$@"
```

so there is nowhere to put it.  I would therefore suggest that you write your own ? `mvn` script which in turn calls the real maven command with the arguments you like (in my experience scripts are more robust than aliases).  Additionally I have recently found myself that the Java versions later than 8 have ... interesting issues... so I really need to have `mvn8`, `mvn11` (and perhaps more) commands anyway.

Another approach that I only started using recently is the Maven wrapper (https://github.com/takari/maven-wrapper) where a `./mvnw` command is placed in your project which then downloads Maven when needed.  This is very useful.  To get started use

```
mvn -N io.takari:maven:wrapper
```

after which `./mvnw` should be directly usable instead of `mvn`.  The interesting part here is that the generated Maven command looks like

```
exec "$JAVACMD" \
  $MAVEN_OPTS \
  -classpath "$MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR/.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar" \
  "-Dmaven.home=${M2_HOME}" "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=${MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR}" \
  ${WRAPPER_LAUNCHER} $MAVEN_CONFIG "$@"
```

and MAVEN_CONFIG is not set earlier in the script.  So for `mvnw` you can set MAVEN_CONFIG to your "-s /settings.xml" string.

Answer (score 6):

### Maven 4

The [`MAVEN_ARGS` environment variable](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#maven_args-environment-variable) is supported and can be used.

### Maven 3.9.0

The [`MAVEN_ARGS` environment variable](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#maven_args-environment-variable) is implemented in Maven 3, starting with version 3.9.0 and can be used if you have sufficiently new version of maven.

### Older Maven 3 versions

There was a feature request [MNG-5824: Support `MAVEN_ARGS` environment variable as a way of supplying default command line arguments](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5824). This was closed unimplemented with a suggestion to use the [`.mvn/maven.config` in project directory](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#mvn-directory)

Answer (score 0):

If (and only if) you are using *Maven Wrapper*, you can set

```
export MAVEN_CONFIG="-s /path/to/settings.xml
```

`MAVEN_ARGS` did not work for me even with Maven Version >= 3.9.0.