# While deploying a mule application in studio 7 I am getting an error

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mulesoft

While deploying a mule application in studio 7 I am getting the below error:

> [ERROR] Could not create local repository at C:\Users\Sourav -> [Help 1]
>
> [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
>
> [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
>
> [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

looks like maven is unable to create a .m2 directory under your home directory. try to run Studio with admin privileges, it should work.

If you don't have the privileges to do that, try to do the following workarounds.

[How to specify an alternate location for the .m2 folder or settings.xml permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649420/how-to-specify-an-alternate-location-for-the-m2-folder-or-settings-xml-permanen)

or

https://howtodoinjava.com/maven/change-local-repository-location/