# installing a jar file created by maven to local repo

Tags: java, maven

I ran the following command to install a custom jar in my local repository:

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```

but when i try this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=E:\jarFiles\utill-1.0.jar -DlocalRepositoryPath=E:\repo
```

it gives me the following error:

```
The artifact information is incomplete or not valid:
[ERROR] [0]  'groupId' is missing.
[ERROR] [1]  'artifactId' is missin
[ERROR] [2]  'packaging' is missing
[ERROR] [3]  'version' is missing.
```

Comment: First the headline of the link talks about `..custom POM`. Furthermore if you like to install the artifact into the local repository you simple can do that by using `mvn install`.

Comment: You need the answer at [Specifying Maven's local repository location as a CLI parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823462/specifying-mavens-local-repository-location-as-a-cli-parameter). If it's a permanent change then you can specify it in your ~/.m2/settings.xml file

Comment: no in that link i sent in the question i meant this line :           If the JAR was built by Apache Maven, it'll contain a pom.xml in a subfolder of the META-INF directory, which will be read by default. In that case, all you need to do is:                                           mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.1:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to provide that information (groupId, artifactId, packaging, version) too.

```
mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=path-to-your-artifact-jar \
                          -DgroupId=your.groupId \
                          -DartifactId=your-artifactId \
                          -Dversion=version \
                          -Dpackaging=jar \
                          -DgeneratePom=true
```

Check [here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/specific-local-repo.html) for more details

Comment: yes that is true but if you check the link i sent in the question, it says that if you have generated your jar files using maven , you dont need to provide this info

Comment: @user3593084 : Check that jar contains pom file under META-INF directory

Comment: yes there is a pom file in the address ..\META-INF\maven\dependMav\utill

Answer (score 8):

This should work.

```
mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.5.2:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file>
```

Comment: Why should that work? Why did the asker's code not work? Please explain in your answer!

Comment: A simple `install:install-file` used `maven-install-plugin:2.4` for me. However, the functionality to use a pom found in the jar was apparently only introduced in `maven-install-plugin:2.5`, so this does in fact solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Hi again guys i wanted to mention something, when i extracted the maven created jar file and copied the POM.xml file in a separate location and installed the jar file by referencing to it . it worked fine but i dont know why my first command din`t work!
here is the command that worked;

```
  mvn install:install-file -Dfile=E:\jarFiles\utill-1.0.jar -DpomFile=E:\jarFiles\pom.xml -DloaclRepositoryPath=E:\repo
```

by the way obviously mvn install , also works fine and installs the jar file to my local repository.

Comment: by the may i wanted to add that the name of the pom file dosent matter because i rerun the command with pom file renamed to Notpom.xml and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think the error says it all. You dont even have to scratch your brain to get info out of it. It is a relevant error and straight to the point.

Refer: 
http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-include-library-manully-into-maven-local-repository/

With your `mvn install` command, you need to provide groupID, artifactId, packaging and version. Check your pom for that information, from which you built the jar..

Sample command:

`mvn install:install-file -Dfile=c:\kaptcha-{version}.jar -DgroupId=com.google.code 
-DartifactId=kaptcha -Dversion={version} -Dpackaging=jar`

Comment: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/examples/custom-pom-installation.html

Comment: Obviously there is some problem with the jar.. did you check for the pom.xml in your jar? Extract it and check for the location ones..

Comment: it is not a big pom file, it was auto generated with maven here is its contents:<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>dependMav</groupId>
  <artifactId>utill</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>utill</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>  
</project>

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, and it was due to a corrupted jar file as suggested in the comments.  I just replaced it and the command worked without any extra switches for groupid, packaging etc (because it was a maven jar already).

It turned out that the jar was corrupted by pushing it from Windows to a git repo then pulling onto a Linux box. The solution was to tell get that jars are binaries to it didn't convert the line endings - see here: [Jar file gets corrupted after pushing to github](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528441/jar-file-gets-corrupted-after-pushing-to-github)