# Jar file gets corrupted after pushing to github

Tags: git, github, git-push, corruption

There is this jar file which is produced locally as a result of the project build. However after it's pushed to github, it gets corrupted. Ran checksum on both local and downloaded jar files and they are different. Cannot even extract it.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because the line endings get converted.

Put this in your .gitattributes file (create it if it doesn't exist):

```
*.jar binary
```

Comment: Did not work. I also tried adding "*.jar -diff" to ".gitattributes" but no luck.

Comment: did you diff the 2 jars?

Comment: yes, it says "Binary files a/main_file...jar and b/downloaded_file...jar differ"

Comment: yes they differ obviously, but what is the first difference you can spot?