# How to execute maven with php (www-data user)?

Tags: java, php, linux, maven

So I need to download all dependencies from a pom.xml to one folder.
That works with that command:

```
mvn -f pom.xml dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=libs
```

It works fine when I run this with the root user from putty, but when I run this with php exec: `exec("mvn -f pom.xml dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=test");` it doesn't work and I'm getting this Error:
***Could not create local repository at /var/www/.m2/repository (LocalRepositoryNotAccessibleException)***

I'm pretty sure this has something to do with permissions because of the www-data user, but I can't figure out what to do (already gave the php file and folder 777 permissions)

Comment: Do you have selinux running?

Comment: @RamanSailopal no

Comment: You can set a different local repository somewhere else where your user can write: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7071791/927493